# upload data to server in background for long time in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have data saved in my sqlite database in my iOS app.The data can be very large let's say 500-600 records.On click of button i am uploading all the data to the server for that i fetch the data from database make a Json for every record & upload record one by one.If the data is large then app will take more time to complete the task.So it's possible meanwhile user move the app in background & do some other stuff on the iOS device.Now i want to know can i run a long network task to background.I have read of `background fetch` but i think it is limited to 10 minutes to how can i upload large data in background mode?

**EDIT**
I have read about `NSURLSession` download task & upload task but it for making long network request for downloading the files & uploading the files only.But i have a Json here which is large & take time to get the response because i am using `NETSUITE` which is very slow for processing data.So is there any workaround for sending `JSON` data only for long time consuming network process?

Comment: Ok.. I would suggest to use NSURLSession for background upload & download.

Comment: can you provide some code ?Is it having any time limit?@Gagan_iOS

Comment: Please go through http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial

Comment: I am asking is there any time limit for the for making network request in background?because it can change a lot of time.

Comment: `MKNetworkKit` supported this feature long before `AFNetworking` ever did, and these both are somewhat superfluous since it is out of the box with `NSURLSession`. I would, still, recommend `AFNetworking`, because it's wrapping and data handling are oh so convenient.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**

The idea with `NSURLSession` is to prepare a `NSURLRequest` in a traditional fashion, construct a task with that request, and let that task proceed with completion handlers using `resume()`.

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: postURL)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { ... }
task.resume()
```

---

**Example**

Here is an example of a `POST` using `NSURLSession`. It will be performed in the background.

This particular example posts a `JSON` payload in the http body, under *payload*.

```
func POST(payload:String) {
    if let transportURL = self.transportURL {
        if let components = NSURLComponents(URL: transportURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) {
            components.path = transportPath
            if let postURL = components.URL {
                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: postURL)
                let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

                request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
                request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

                // send it the username and the text message

                let bodyString:String = "payload=" + payload
                request.HTTPBody = bodyString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                    data, response, error in

                    // Your completion handler code here
                    // Check if response didn't work
                    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                        if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                            print("\(response)")
                            return
                        }
                    }
                    if (error != nil) {
                        print("\(error)")
                        return
                    }
                }
                task.resume()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post it for objective c & for also to run in background.

Comment: Background: that task essentially runs in the background. Only the notifications are in the thread that initiated the `resume`.

Comment: why you are not writing any code in app delegate file?@SwiftArchitect

Comment: I have no idea about swift i work in obj-c so to continue the network request i would call the method in app delegate.

Comment: pleas suggest what is the best option here ?

Comment: All comments that have been upvoted (**NSURLSession** by Gagan_iOS and **AFNetworking** by Saheb Roy) are equally valid. And so is the link to raywenderlich.com.